# How to disallow consecutive five digits and more using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, antd

I would like to disallow if the string contains consecutive five digits and more like: 12345, 11111, 123456.

I have got success in disallowing any number in string using following regex:

`/^[^0-9]+$/`

I have created a [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l4429ym3kl). I want to disallow five consecutive numbers/digits. Currently it is disallowing any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex matching 5 consecutive digits is `\d{5}`.

To **disallow** such a string (actually, even more consecutive digits),
at **any position** in the source string, this regex should be put:

- inside a *negative lookup*: `(?!...)`,
- after a regex matching any number (zero or more) of any chars `.*?`
  (reluctant variant).

After this negative lookup, there should be a regex matching the whole string:
`.+` (I assume that you are not interested in an empty string, so I put `+`,
not `*`).

The whole regex above should be preceded with `^` and followed with `$` anchors.

So the whole regex can be: `^(?!.*?\d{5}).+$`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good website for testing your regex:

https://regex101.com/

**You could try this:**

```
/^[0-9]{5,}$/
```

5 numbers or more will pass the regex.

Comment: This regex passes any string containing 5 or more digits and nothing more,
but the requirement is different. Any string to be passed can contain other
chars (eg. spaces, letters and punctation). It can contain even digits,
but no more than 5 in a row.